# How to create a bytebuddy agent that intercepts a field setter from annotated field?

Tags: java, code-generation, byte-buddy

What I am trying to do is basically match a class's field with an annotaion and them intercept the field's getter and setter.

```java
 public class Foo {

    @Sensitive
    private String Blah;
```

Here is the code for my agent:

```java
    private static AgentBuilder createAgent() {
        return new AgentBuilder
                .Default()
                .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
                .type(ElementMatchers.is(FieldTypeMatcher.class).and(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(Foo.class)))
                .transform(((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) ->
                        builder
                        .method(method -> method.getActualName().contains(typeDescription.getActualName()))
                        .intercept(Advice.to(Interceptor.class))
                ));
    }
```

I though I could match the field's name with the method's signature but I had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `Foo` has a getter and setter for `Blah`?

In this case, I recommend a custom `ElementMatcher` implementation such as:

```
class FieldMatcher implements ElementMatcher<MethodDescription> {
  @Override
  public boolean matches(MethodDescription target) {
    String fieldName;
    if (target.getName().startsWith("set") || target.getName().startsWith("get")) {
      fieldName = target.substring(3, 4).toLowerCase() + target.substring(4);
    } else if (target.getName().startsWith("is")) {
      fieldName = target.substring(2, 3).toLowerCase() + target.substring(3);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    target.getDeclaringType()
      .getDeclaredFields()
      .filter(named)
      .getOnly()
      .getDeclaredAnnotations()
      .isAnnotationPresent(Sensitive.class);
  }
}
```

This matcher checks if a method is a getter or setter, locates the corresponding field and checks for the annotation being present on it.

Comment: Hi Rafael, thank you so much for answering so fast! I get the gist of what you're doing, although my IDE tells me that it can't resolve `.isAnnotationPresent`. I'm using bytebuddy 1.10.1 should I be using a different version?

Comment: I was missing a step in the DSL, this is now fixed.